# How to add ExoPlayer to android app?

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me the link to download ExoPlayer library for android app development n how to use it?

Thx in advance for your kind answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a github for exoplayer, which contains the exoplayer library and an android demo app. You have to build the library.

The documentation indicates how to do it. Basically you can just do a gradle build (provided you cloned the repo and installed git).